# Using route data values with htmlhelpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, html-helper

I want to create a helper that would look something like this and

```
namespace MvcApplication.Helpers
{
     public static class Extensions
     {
          public static string Test(this HtmlHelper helper, string routeValue1, string routeValue2)
          {
               return "Something";

          }
     }
}
```

Is there a way to access ViewContext.RouteData.Values from Test without passing route values as parameters? Is the only possible alternative

```
public static string Test(this HtmlHelper helper, ViewContext vc)
          {
               return "Something";

          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a property of HtmlHelper class:

```
      public static string Test(this HtmlHelper helper)
      {
           var routeValue = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["key"];
           return "Something";

      }
```

Comment: so RouteCollection accesses ViewContext.RouteData values and keys? Helped a lot!

Comment: sorry I've made a mistake you need helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["key"]

Comment: MajoB i would appreciate your assistance on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402530/how-to-get-route-name-from-action?noredirect=1#comment43250970_27402530