# How to get route name from action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using MapMvcAttributeRoutes to set routes in my MVC application. Now I have a doubt is it possible to access a route name from action Index?

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{language}/Home/Index", Name = "Home.Index")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
      //access route name Home.Index here?
      return View();
}
```

I wanted to say I tried something, but do not relly know where to start. I did some researching in forums and SO, but did not find any valid answer.

**EDIT**

In order to fully understand my question here is an example. Each view contains a partial view (header) that generates links for all languages of a current view. Some actions/views use AttributeRoutes and some use default routing from routeconfig. How can I decide when to call RouteUrl and when to call Action?

Comment: Why do you need the route name?

Comment: So I can generate RouteUrl for all available languages

Comment: You can do Url.Action to generate the url, otherwise check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363211/how-can-i-get-the-route-name-in-controller-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Is this possible with MapMvcAttributeRoutes?

Comment: I think Url.Action will handle MapMvcAttributes, but you can check as for the question link, I'm no sure

Comment: I have update my question, please check it

Comment: you can read this article http://haacked.com/archive/2010/11/28/getting-the-route-name-for-a-route.aspx/

Comment: You can see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621674/multiple-routes-assigned-to-one-method-how-to-determine-which-route-was-called/54369246#54369246 to see how to do this.